# JSON: dies on decoding when created file with pretty print

Tags: json, perl, pretty-print

Why do I get this error, when I use the pretty print version?

> '"' expected, at character offset 2 (before "(end of string)") at ./perl.pl line 29.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(utf-8)';
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new->utf8;
my $hashref = { 
    'muster, hanß' => { 
        'hello' => { 
            year => 2000, 
            color => 'green' 
        }
    } 
};

my $utf8_encoded_json_text = $json->pretty->encode( $hashref ); # leads to a die
#my $utf8_encoded_json_text = $json->encode( $hashref ); # works

open my $fh, '>', 'testfile.json' or die $!;
print $fh $utf8_encoded_json_text;
close $fh;

open $fh, '<', 'testfile.json' or die $!;
$utf8_encoded_json_text = readline $fh;
close $fh;
$hashref = decode_json( $utf8_encoded_json_text );
say Dumper $hashref;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when you read the file back in, you're using `readline`, and only reading the first line of the file. When pretty is off, the entire output is on one line. When pretty is on, the JSON is spread out over multiple lines, so you're passing invalid truncated JSON to `decode_json`.

Read the entire content by using `local $/ = undef;` or [slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSlurp) or whatever else you want.